# How to keep inner outline groups hidden when maximizing outer group

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter

I have written a python script which groups rows of an Excel file via the [XlsxWriter Outlines and Grouping](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_outlines.html#outlines) feature.

My file has two groups, one nested in the other one. Here's a minimal example:

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('outline.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

worksheet.set_row(1, None, None, {'level': 1, 'hidden': True})
worksheet.set_row(2, None, None, {'level': 2, 'hidden': True})
worksheet.set_row(3, None, None, {'level': 2, 'hidden': True})
worksheet.set_row(4, None, None, {'level': 1, 'hidden': True})

workbook.close()
```

This generates both groups in the 'hidden' state. When I maximize the first group, the second (inner) group also gets maximized.

How can I prevent the inner group from maximizing when the outer group gets maximized?

The only way to do this, that I know, is to maximize the groups and then minimize the inner and then the outer group by hand. When saved, closed and reopened the groups do not maximize both when maximizing the outer one. So Excel obviously has a way to store this information somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the `collapsed` property at the right level. See the 
[Working with Outlines and Grouping](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_outlines.html#outlines) section of the XlsxWriter docs.

Here is a working example:

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('outline.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

worksheet.set_row(1, None, None, {'level': 1, 'hidden': True})
worksheet.set_row(2, None, None, {'level': 2, 'hidden': True})
worksheet.set_row(3, None, None, {'level': 2, 'hidden': True})
worksheet.set_row(4, None, None, {'level': 1, 'hidden': True, 'collapsed': True})

workbook.close()
```

**Output:**

[image]